# How to include jquery.js before other javascript includes?

Tags: javascript

I'm using a jquery carousel on my site and getting some errors on some pages. My jquery guru said the cause of the problem is that currently jquery.js gets included after other javascript includes.

Making the jquery.js the first include will fix the problem according to him. How do I change the order of the javascript includes?

Comment: If you do a view source, where is jquery.js?  I don't recall _not_ seeing it first.

Comment: in 7th place, after jquery.once.js?v=1.2, drupal.js, admin_devel.js, memcache.js, video.js and extlink.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [hook_js_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7) to change the order of js presentation.

For example, edit your theme's template.php:

```
function youtheme_js_alter(&$javascript) {

  $javascript['misc/jquery.js']['group'] = -500;

  $javascript['misc/jquery.js']['weight'] = -500;

}
```

Comment: thanks. I found the problem, it was caused by a malformed drupal_add_js() function which caused the order of the includes to get messed up. Here is the post for future reference: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7#comment-17039  Your answer pointed in the right direction (weights), so I'll accept it.