# drupal.js is loading before jquery.js

Tags: javascript

I have face this problem often in my drupal site. The `drupal.js` file is loading before `jquery.js`, so i get the "uncaught jQuery is not defined" error.

I have been using memcached also in my site.

But I can fix the error by the following steps

1. Restart memcached
2. Restart Apache
3. Cache clear
4. Run the cron

After doing the steps the jQuery is loading properly.

Now, i want to know the reason why the `drupal.js` loading before `jquery.js`?

**FYI : This is happening, When I enable/disable any modules/features through UI**

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/19906/10041) answer and [this comment](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7#comment-17039). Hope this helps.

Comment: are you using drupal_add_js() in any module file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be because of cache that might cause

1. Check if you installed `jquery_update` module
2. in themes info check if there you have declared jquery

   3.check if in any module **`hook_init`**() you are adding your js with weight.

if you install jquery update module you dont need to add jquery plugin in info file

if you have any clarification regarding the js weight and so on read the following links will be helpful

https://www.drupal.org/node/756722

https://www.drupal.org/node/304255

Answer (score 1):

Use `hook_js_alter` see the below example code.

```
function MODULENAME_js_alter(&$js) {
drupal_add_js('mise/drupal.js', 'external');
drupal_add_js('mise/jquery.js', 'external');    
}
```

Comment: It is not a drupal normal behavior, but something strange in my site. I need to find out that. your solutions is a temporary one.

Comment: That's the problem @Leopathu: it's not normal behaviour, but we don't have access to your code, so it's pretty difficult to suggest what might be going wrong. However...check your codebase for `hook_js_alter()` implementations, maybe some rogue code is doing something it shouldn't. Also temporarily disable aggregation and any modules (e.g. advagg) that change that process. Check theme preprocesses for the html template, try with a different theme to see if the problem persists, and so on

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Clive, you comment help more to find out the issue.

In my case, we have used the drupal_add_js outside of the functions/hooks without any conditions as the following code,

```
<?php

// Adds the custom css file into the module.
$module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'kf_book_quiz');
drupal_add_js($module_path . '/kf_book_quiz.js');
drupal_add_css($module_path . '/kf_book_quiz.css');
drupal_add_css($module_path . '/kf_book_quiz_rwd.css');
module_load_include('inc','quiz','quiz.admin');

/**
 * Implements hook_init()
 */
function kf_book_quiz_init() {

}
```

It is not a proper way to add the js into module. This would break the js queue structure.
We should add js only where it is needed, we could use [hook_preprocess_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) to add js for needed place with conditions.